# colsep not working as expected in the longtblr environment and how to format "remark" in the longtblr?

Tags: longtblr

I have the following table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}   
\begin{longtblr}
    [caption={Concept analysis for derailleur},
    label={tab:BCR_concepts},
    remark{Note}= {$K^k$ = stiffness mechanism, $M^k$ = mass of compliant member, $S^k$ = bending stress, $F^k$ = output force, $N^k$ = safety factor}]
    {colsep=6pt,
    colspec={X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]},
    hline{1,2,Z}={solid},
    columns={font=\small}}
    \SetCell[r=1,c=1]{c}{Parameter} & Concept 1 & Concept 2 & Concept 3 & Concept 4 \\
    $\gamma$ & 0.8517 & 0.85 & 0.8517 & 0.85\\
    $K_{\Theta}$ & 2.6762 & 2.68 & 2.6762 & 2.68\\
    $n_e$ & - & - & 14 & 2\\
    $K^k$ & $2 \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c$ & $\gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c$ & $2 n_e \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c$ & $n_e \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c$\\
    $F^k$ & $4K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta)$ & $K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta)$ & $4 n_e K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta)$ & $n_e K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta)$\\
    $M^k$ & $bhl_c \rho_1$ & $bhl_c \rho_1$ & $n_e bhl_c \rho_2$ & $n_e bhl_c \rho_2$\\
    $S^k$ & $F^k ah/(4I)$ & $F^k ah/(2I)$ & $F^k ah/(4 n_e I)$ & $F^k ah/(2 n_e I)$\\
    $N^k$ & $S_{max}/S_k$ & $S_{max}/S_k$ & $S_{max}/S_k$ & $S_{max}/S_k$ \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

And the output is as follows:

[image]

1. In the 6th row, there is an improper column separation. How to fix that?
2. How to format the remark so that the content is aligned after ":" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents in some cells in 6th row are to wide that can be placed in cells. Possible solution is:

- reduce font size to `\footnotesize`
- remove spaces at beginning and at end of table
- for first column use `Q` type
- `remark` text you can enclose in `\parbox` (see MWE below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Concept analysis for derailleur},
  label = {tab:BCR_concepts},
remark{Note}={\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth - 3em}
              {$K^k$ = stiffness mechanism, $M^k$ = mass of compliant member, $S^k$ = bending stress, $F^k$ = output force, $N^k$ = safety factor}
              }
                ]{colsep=4pt,
                  colspec={@{} Q[c, mode=math] *{4}{X[c, mode=math]} @{}},
                  columns={font=\footnotesize},
                  row{1} ={mode=text},
                  hline{1,2,Z}={solid},
                 }
Parameter   & Concept 1 & Concept 2 & Concept 3 & Concept 4     \\
%
\gamma      & 0.8517 & 0.85 & 0.8517 & 0.85\\
K_{\Theta}  & 2.6762 & 2.68 & 2.6762 & 2.68\\
n_e         & - & - & 14 & 2\\
K^k         & 2 \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c & \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c & 2 n_e \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c & n_e \gamma K_{\Theta}EI/l_c\\
F^k         & 4K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta) & K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta) & 4 n_e K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta) & n_e K^k\Theta/(\gamma l_c cos\Theta)\\
M^k         & bhl_c \rho_1 & bhl_c \rho_1 & n_e bhl_c \rho_2 & n_e bhl_c \rho_2\\
S^k         & F^k ah/(4I) & F^k ah/(2I) & F^k ah/(4 n_e I) & F^k ah/(2 n_e I)\\
N^k         & S_{max}/S_k & S_{max}/S_k & S_{max}/S_k & S_{max}/S_k \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is your table really log table (spanning several pages)? If not you may consider to use `talltblr` instead of it.

Comment: What are the benefits of 'talltblr' over 'longtblr'?

Comment: @RounakNiloy, it can be inserted into `table` float meanwhile `longtblr` not.